# Edit Style of UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, styles, ios8, uitableview

I'd like to add a new function to my MyTableView.swift file, but i get an error:

```
Overriding method with selector 'initWithStyle: reuseIdentifier:' has incompatible type '(UITableViewCellStyle, String) -> MyTableViewCell'
```

This is the code, which i like to add:

```
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) 
}
```

Whole code MyTableView.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let medColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.973, green: 0.388, blue: 0.173, alpha: 1)

    init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
        super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show all contents of MyTableView.swift if possible.

Comment: @Kirsteins I posted the whole code in the question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that `(UITableViewCellStyle, String)` type is not equal to `(UITableViewCellStyle, String?)`
If you look at init method of UItableViewCell, it looks like this -
`init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)`

**Fix**
Chane reuseIdentifier type for `String` to an optional string `String?`

```
 override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
    super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
```